# Error: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. from v-item-group

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I use Vuex with Vuetify.

I am trying to create a `v-dialog` component. The form appears fine but the images from `v-item-group` are missing.

Vue Component

```
<template>
    <v-row justify="center">
        <v-dialog v-model="isDoorDimDialog" max-width="800px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">Add</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">Select Door Dimensions:</span>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-container>
                        <v-row>

                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                <v-text-field 
                                    label="Height*" 
                                    required>
                                </v-text-field>
                            </v-col>

                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                <v-text-field 
                                    label="Width" 
                                    hint="example of helper text only on focus">
                                </v-text-field>
                            </v-col>

                            <v-col>
                            <v-item-group v-model="selectedType" mandatory>
                                <v-row>
                                    <v-col
                                        v-for="(img, name) in imgTypes"
                                        :key="name"
                                        cols="12"
                                        md="6"
                                    >
                                        <v-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }">
                                            <v-img
                                                :src="`{{img}}`"
                                                height="150"
                                                class="text-right pa-2"
                                                @click="toggle"
                                            >
                                                <v-scroll-y-transition>
                                                    <div
                                                        v-if="active"
                                                        class="display-3 flex-grow-1 text-center"
                                                    >
                                                    Active
                                                    </div>
                                                </v-scroll-y-transition>
                                            </v-img>
                                            <h3>{{name}} Door</h3>
                                        </v-item>
                                    </v-col>
                                </v-row>
                            </v-item-group>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-container>
                    <small>*indicates required field</small>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                        <v-btn 
                            color="blue darken-1" 
                            text 
                            @click="isDoorDimDialog = false">Close
                        </v-btn>
                        <v-btn 
                            color="blue darken-1" 
                            text 
                            @click="isDoorDimDialog = false">Save
                        </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-row>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState('addDoors', {
            imgTypes: state => state.imgTypes
        }),
        isDoorDimDialog: {
            set(isDoorDimDialog) {
                this.$store.commit('addDoors/setIsDoorDimDialog', isDoorDimDialog);
            },
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.addDoors.isDoorDimDialog;
            }
        },
        selectedType: {
            set(selectedType) {
                this.$store.commit('addDoors/setSelectedType', selectedType);
            },
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.addDoors.selectedType;
            }
        }
    },

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Vuex

```
export const addDoors = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        isDoorDimDialog: false,
        imgTypes: {
            Standard: '@/assets/door-icons/icon-doors-standard.png',
            Sliding: '@/assets/door-icons/icon-doors-sliding.png',
            Balcony: '@/assets/door-icons/icon-doors-balcony.png'
        },
        selectedType: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        setIsDoorDimDialog(state, isDoorDimDialog) {
            state.isDoorDimDialog = isDoorDimDialog;
        },
        setSelectedType(state, selectedType) {
            state.selectedType = selectedType;
        }
    },
    actions: {

    }
}
```

After I have added the `v-item-group` I get the error:

> [Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node.

The images do not show up either.

How does my code create multiple root nodes exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a single child inside a `<v-item>`. Currently you have two, a `<v-img>` and a `<h3>`.

`v-item` is a renderless component. It doesn't render any elements itself, it just renders the contents of its default slot. If that slot contains multiple items then they'll all be returned, leading to the error you're seeing.

The relevant code in Vuetify is here:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/7f7391d76dc44f7f7d64f30ad7e0e429c85597c8/packages/vuetify/src/components/VItemGroup/VItem.ts#L53

You should be seeing an error message from the component itself:

> v-item should only contain a single element

Try wrapping the two nodes in a single parent.

Comment: I got 2 different errors in the console. The one I added above which was in `red` and another one in `yellow`.

I paid attention only to the one in `red`